# Include your app when someone takes a screenshot on the device Android

Tags: java, android, mobile

when you take a screenshot, and click share, there are some apps that are suggested by the device like whatsapp, facebook,(there is  a list), how to include my application to that list? what is the feature called? 
the Android device gives you an option of sharing it with
Add to Maps, camera, Facebook, set as profile picture, whatsapp, Hangouts, save to google drive,  etc
What is the name of the feature? Could someone, point me to a tutorial about it?

Comment: maybe your looking for services like [addthis](http://www.addthis.com/get/share) or [sharethis](http://www.sharethis.com/). [addtoany](https://www.addtoany.com/buttons/customize/add_services) has a Custom Services where you can probably add your own service.

Comment: You just need to have some activity with an intent filter specifying  ACTION_SHARE on the mime type they are sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [Share and View Actions](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html)

The documentation should walk you through it fairly well, but the basics are that you need to add an `<intent-filter>` to one of your Activities in your Manifest file, and declare the type of data that you would like to handle. The example given in the documentation is:

```
<activity android:name="ShareActivity">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```